# Issue with filtering array value from different array in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have `if/else` condition in `List.vue` component, Where it always falling under condition of else. not sure why ?

HelloWorld.vue **:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.SName">
      <BaseAccordian>
        <template v-slot:title>{{ box.SName }}</template>
        <template v-slot:content>
          <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.TName">
            {{ paint.TName }}
          </div>
          <List
            :content="matchingdata"
            :SName="box.SName"
          />
        </template>
      </BaseAccordian>
    </div>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import { tab } from "./tab";
import { tabb } from "./tabb";
import { tabsandcontent } from "./tabsandcontent";
import BaseAccordian from "./BaseAccordian.vue";
import List from "./List.vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    BaseAccordian,
    List,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      boxes: [],
      paints: [],
      matchingdata: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    tab().then((r) => {
      this.boxes = r.data;
    });
    tabb().then((r) => {
      this.paints = r.data;
    });
    tabsandcontent().then((r) => {
      this.matchingData = r.data;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

List.vue **:**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="matchingData.length > 0" class="line">
      <div
        v-for="match in matchingData"
        :key="match.PD"
        :class="{
          green: match.OverallStatus === 'healthy',
          red: match.OverallStatus === 'down',
        }"
      >
        {{ match.OverallStatus }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else><p>No matching data</p></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  props: {
    content: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    SourceDatabaseName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data: function () {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    matchingData() {
      return this.content.filter((a) => a.SName === this.SName);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Functionality which I am trying to achieve **:**

I have three arrays like `matchingdata`, `boxes` and `paints`
and I have common array name called `SName` exists in `matchingdata` and  `boxes` arrays.

Comment: @tryzord I noticed you removed the axios request from the codesandbox (and removed codesandbox too). If you removed that because request was failing, then, FYI, it works after allowing "Insecure Content" from site-settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in `HelloWorld.vue`.

Replace both instances of `matchingdata` by `matchingData` and it will work.

Here's the final file.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.SourceDatabaseName">
      <BaseAccordian>
        <template v-slot:title>{{ box.SourceDatabaseName }}</template>
        <template v-slot:content>
          <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.TargetDatabaseName">
            {{ paint.TargetDatabaseName }}
          </div>
          <List
            :content="matchingData"
            :SourceDatabaseName="box.SourceDatabaseName"
          />
        </template>
      </BaseAccordian>
    </div>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import { tab } from "./tab";
import { tabb } from "./tabb";
import { tabsandcontent } from "./tabsandcontent";
import BaseAccordian from "./BaseAccordian.vue";
import List from "./List.vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    BaseAccordian,
    List,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      boxes: [],
      paints: [],
      matchingData: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    tab().then((r) => {
      this.boxes = r.data;
    });
    tabb().then((r) => {
      this.paints = r.data;
    });
    tabsandcontent().then((r) => {
      this.matchingData = r.data;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```